# MySQL Trigger with INNER JOIN and Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, subquery

I am working with 3 tables as follows:

[image]

I am trying to create a trigger which does the following: If the price of a laptop gets increased by any amount then decrease by 5 the price of each PC made by the maker of that laptop.

I am using a join and subquery in order to select the correct maker. It **looks** okay to me but clearly isn't. When I create the query it is enter okay but when I update and increase a price of a laptop the price of the relevant pcs don't decrease by 5.

This is my best attempt at the trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER price_update AFTER UPDATE
ON laptop
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF(NEW.price > OLD.price)
    THEN 
    UPDATE pc
    INNER JOIN product
    ON product.model = pc.model
    SET price = price - 5
    WHERE product.maker IN (SELECT maker
                            FROM product
                            WHERE model = NEW.model);
    END IF;
    END;
$$
```

Please excuse any ignorance I am new to MySQL. Any advice much appreciated.

**EDIT:** Feel stupid! It works fine. I was checking the wrong models in the pc table.

Comment: try `SET pc.price = pc.price - 5`

Comment: Thanks for making me recheck everything. It turns out it is working fine I was checking the wrong models in the pcs table. :/

Comment: let me add an answer it would be helpful for others.